# Do stellar model luminosities include neutrino losses?

Tags: astrophysics, neutrinos, stars, stellar-evolution

I have had a sudden crisis in my understanding of the published outputs from stellar evolutionary model calculations.

Usually these models output a "luminosity" that one can then use, along with the temperature and an atmosphere model to work out how bright the star would be (in terms of magnitudes) through various filters (e.g. U, B, V etc.)

But do the quoted luminosities *only* include electromagnetic radiation or does it also include the neutrino losses (which then obviously make no contribution to the electromagnetic flux)? This would be a 2.3% effect in the case of the Sun, where the usually quoted value of $L_{\odot} = 3.83\times 10^{26}$ W does *not* include neutrinos.

And whether the models do or don't include the neutrino losses, where can I find those separately?

Comment: Uh ... good question. I would *assume* that the meaning is intended to be equivalent to the measured luminosities which means only energy in electromagnetic channels. (And I would argue that this is the correct practice.) But I don't know what is actually done.